# Anaconda Navigator and Spider not opening (Shell works)

Tags: python, user-interface, anaconda, python-3.7

The navigator was working fine till about November and then it stopped working after I installed Cuda 10.0. I uninstalled Cuda and that did nothing. I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it but that did nothing. There is no error message or feedback at all when I click the icon or right-click and run. The python shell works but none of the guis work. I tried updating the navigator and that did not solve the issue. I also read all the other posts about the navigator not working I could find. When I tried installing another navigator, the navigator opened but the GUI had all broken buttons. I was too busy to deal with the issue at the time but now that I have the time I want to get back. Also something to note, the anaconda version that worked was 3.4, none of the newer versions have worked on my PC ever. 
I am a beginner python programmer.

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? Have you tried erasing all traces of Anaconda/Conda before reinstalling (starting from scratch) ?